# npm install -g on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed node.js using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I would like to use `npm install -g` without using `sudo` so I had setup by following this [instruction](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)

I tried to install bower using `npm install -g bower` the bower package has been installed at *~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower* successfully

My problem is that I cannot execute bower using `~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower`, I must use `node ~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower`, why do I need extra `node` in front of the executable bower?

I also have got the same result with *gulp*, *grunt* and whatever installed packages with `npm install -g`

Please help me to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that for some reason your `bower` binary is not executable - can you check that, and also post the error back here?

You shouldn't need the path at all if you've followed those instructions, the final section adds your .npm_packages/bin directory to the path, so you should just be able to run `bower` on its own.

Comment: I had no ideas what was going on but after re-installing node.js and npm, plus a few times restarting, it just worked, thanks